# 2 x Intel Xeon 5645 vs 1 x Intel Core i7 3.9Ghz: what is a fundamental difference?

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit

I would like to understand a fundamental difference between the two following setups:

> - 2 x Intel Xeon 5645 6x2.40 GHz + DDR3 memory
> - 1 x Intel Core i7 4x3.9Ghz + DDR3 memory

I am running a LAMP stack on the server with much of the work done by MySQL database and PHP doing some light presentation work and overall orchestration. Quieries are frequent but quite light (index lookup + couple of joins).

Type of load is many many reads and a few writes. (Not much I/O as most of the data is available at InnoDb buffer pool).

Answer (score 4):

The Xeon is a 9 year old processor (very old) but does come with a lot of functionality designed to keep your server running for longer (google 'RAS')

The only i7's with 4 cores at 3.9Ghz seem to be mobile processors (a bad idea for acting as a server) but even if you've got the wrong details they're all desktop/laptop processors missing those RAS features which could easily cause downtime for your platform.

If all you care about is performance there's really only one way to know which is best, by testing them with the same load.

Comment: I believe old means the obsolete chipset as well. What kind of trouble can it bring along?

Comment: It's so old that the hardware is unlikely to have manufacturer support still, which pro's consider a big no-no

Comment: Is RRAS supposed to mean RAS?

Comment: Yes, I'm showing my age, RRAS was something altogether different, thanks for spotting that :)